# Составить запрос

Tags: sql, firebird

[image: на рисунке]

Имеется таблица (на рисунке сверху). Нужно её сгруппировать по следующим правилам: выбрать выделенные строки (условие: TOP между MIN и MAX данной строки), но строки MIN заменить на минимальное из MIN в подгруппе (с равным MID), MAX соответственно на максимальное в подгруппе и сохранить значиния CR_W, которые только 1 раз встречаются в каждой подгруппе в строке с CREDIT=TRUE. Подгруппы могут иметь 1-3 строк. Результат в таблице на рисунке снизу.

Comment: Можете привести запрос, которым вы пытались получить необходимые выходные данные.

Comment: SELECT ID, MID, NAME, COUNT,
(SELECT min(MIN) FROM FTABLE r WHERE r.MID=MID) AS MIN,
(SELECT max(MAX) FROM FTABLE r WHERE r.MID=MID) AS MAX,
TOP,
(SELECT CR_W FROM FTABLE r WHERE r.MID=MID) AS CR_W,
FROM FTABLE
WHERE MIN<TOP AND MAX>TOP
GROUP BY MID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант без вложенных запросов:

```
SELECT 
      t2."ID"
      ,t1."MID"
      ,t1."NAME"
      ,t1."COUNT"
      ,min(t1."MIN")
      ,max(t1."MAX")
      ,t1."TOP"
      ,max(t1."CR_W")
FROM FTABLE t1
JOIN FTABLE t2 ON t1."MID" = t2."MID"
WHERE t2."MIN" < t2."TOP" AND t2."MAX" > t2."TOP"
GROUP BY t2."ID", t1."MID", t1."NAME", t1."COUNT", t1."TOP";
```

Comment: Благодарю, так приятнее выглядит, а то я в этих вложенных заблудился уже, нужно остальное так же будет переписать

Comment: а вот этот вложенный возможно тоже без вложений развернуть? в том месте где select sum. там просто max берется по всей подгруппе, а сумму нужно посчитать уже с учетом фильтра.